# Update database settings in properties file in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I am new to spring
I am trying to create a Database Manager page which shows the database details on page load and updates the database settings when the user press submit

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/) and set the database settings in properties file.

I managed to update the database settings in properties file programmatically.  When I retrieved the database settings using the following code

```
DriverManagerDataSource databaseSource = (DriverManagerDataSource)context.getBean("dataSource");
databaseSource.getUsername();
```

I managed to get the old value and unable to get the new value

This is the mapping in applicationContext.xml file

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:/bundle/database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

I checked the properties file and found it to be updated with the latest input.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

P.S I am using JSF1.2 with Spring 3

**Update**

Just making my requirement simple.  I am creating a setparate dbsettings page, so that when user wishes to connect to different database he/she can just enter the details in dbsettings page and connect

**Update**

I used this code to retrieve the application context

```
private ApplicationContext context;
```

....

```
ServletContext servletContext = FacesUtil.getServletContext();
    this.context = WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
```

If I change it into AbstractApplicationContext what change do I need in the above code?

**UPDATE**

```
this.context = (AbstractApplicationContext)WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    String valueForTheProperty = "";


    context.refresh();
```

When I add the lines above I am getting

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:599)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:377)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:263)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:101)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
$Proxy1.getDatabasePasswordFromSettings(Unknown Source)
com.smartcall.delegate.DbSettingsDelegate.getDatabasePassswordFromSettings(DbSettingsDelegate.java:38)
com.smartcall.bean.DbSettingsBean.loadDatabaseSettings(DbSettingsBean.java:49)
com.smartcall.bean.DbSettingsBean.<init>(DbSettingsBean.java:41)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:185)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:368)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:230)
com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:86)
javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:68)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:112)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:246)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.createComponent(ComponentHandler.java:224)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:139)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:109)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:95)
com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:524)
com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.nextTimestamp(RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.java:85)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:526)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:535)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:493)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:377)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:263)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:101)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
$Proxy1.getDatabasePasswordFromSettings(Unknown Source)
com.smartcall.delegate.DbSettingsDelegate.getDatabasePassswordFromSettings(DbSettingsDelegate.java:38)
com.smartcall.bean.DbSettingsBean.loadDatabaseSettings(DbSettingsBean.java:49)
com.smartcall.bean.DbSettingsBean.<init>(DbSettingsBean.java:41)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:185)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:368)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:230)
com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:86)
javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:68)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:112)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:246)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.createComponent(ComponentHandler.java:224)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:139)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:109)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:95)
com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:524)
com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
```

When I comment out the line

```
context.refresh()
```

application is working fine.  Plz help

**UPDATE**

DBSettingBean

```
public DbSettingsBean()
{
    dbSettingsDelegate = new DbSettingsDelegate();

    loadDatabaseSettings();
    submitButton.setRendered(false);
    testButton.setRendered(true);
}

public void loadDatabaseSettings()
{
    this.setUserName(dbSettingsDelegate.getDatabaseUserNameFromSettings());
    this.setPassword(dbSettingsDelegate.getDatabasePassswordFromSettings());
    this.setServerName(dbSettingsDelegate.getDatabaseServerNameFromSettings());
    this.setDataSourceName(dbSettingsDelegate.getDatabaseNameFromSettings());
}

public HtmlOutputText getText()
{
    return text;
}



public void setText(HtmlOutputText text)
{
    this.text = text;
}



public HtmlAjaxCommandButton getSubmitButton()
{
    return submitButton;
}



public void setSubmitButton(HtmlAjaxCommandButton submitButton)
{
    this.submitButton = submitButton;
}



public HtmlCommandButton getTestButton()
{
    return testButton;
}



public void setTestButton(HtmlCommandButton testButton)
{
    this.testButton = testButton;
}



public HtmlOutputText getStatusMessageComponent()
{
    return statusMessageComponent;
}

public void setStatusMessageComponent(HtmlOutputText statusMessageComponent)
{
    this.statusMessageComponent = statusMessageComponent;
}

public UIInput getPassworder()
{
    return passworder;
}

public void setPassworder(UIInput passworder)
{
    this.passworder = passworder;
}

public String getServerName()
{
    return serverName;
}

public void setServerName(String serverName)
{
    this.serverName = serverName;
}

public String getDataSourceName()
{
    return dataSourceName;
}

public void setDataSourceName(String dataSourceName)
{
    this.dataSourceName = dataSourceName;
}

public String getUserName()
{
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName)
{
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword()
{
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password)
{
    this.password = password;
}

public String testWhetherTheConnectionExists()
{       
    return dbSettingsDelegate.checkWhetherDatabaseConnectionExists(getUserName(), getPassword(), getDataSourceName(),getServerName());
}
```

and..

DbSettingsDelegate

```
public DbSettingsDelegate()
{
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("Dbsettings delegate: "+FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        dbSettingsService = (DbSettingsService) ServiceLocator
                        .getInstance().getService(
                        ServiceLocator.Services.DBSETTINGS);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        logger.debug("error in AddressBookDelegate constructor", e);
    }
}

public String getDatabaseUserNameFromSettings()
{
    return dbSettingsService.getDatabaseUserNameFromSettings();
}

public String getDatabasePassswordFromSettings()
{
    return dbSettingsService.getDatabasePasswordFromSettings();
}

public String getDatabaseServerNameFromSettings()
{
    return dbSettingsService.getDatabaseServerNameFromSettings();
}

public String getDatabaseNameFromSettings()
{
    return dbSettingsService.getDatabaseNameFromSettings();
}

public String checkWhetherDatabaseConnectionExists(String theUserName,String thePassword,String theDatabaseName,String theServerName)
{
    return dbSettingsService.checkWhetherTheDatabaseConnectionExists(theUserName, thePassword, theDatabaseName, theServerName);
}
```

and this is the code to retrieve database details to show to the user

```
ServletContext servletContext = FacesUtil.getServletContext();
    this.context = (AbstractApplicationContext)WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    String valueForTheProperty = "";
    DriverManagerDataSource databaseSource =  null;

    context.refresh();
    databaseSource = (DriverManagerDataSource)context.getBean("dataSource");



    if(theProperty.equalsIgnoreCase("username"))
    {
        valueForTheProperty = databaseSource.getUsername();
    }       
    else if(theProperty.equalsIgnoreCase("password"))
    {
        valueForTheProperty = databaseSource.getPassword();
    }
    else if(theProperty.equalsIgnoreCase("server"))
    {           
        valueForTheProperty = this.splitUrlAndGetValueForKey(databaseSource.getUrl(), "server");
        System.out.println("Server:  "+valueForTheProperty);
    }
    else
    {
        valueForTheProperty = this.splitUrlAndGetValueForKey(databaseSource.getUrl(), "databasename");
    }
```

**UPDATE**
When I debugged the code I found these lines in the console.  When `context.refresh()` is called

```
Dec 28, 2010 3:22:44 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Dec 28, 2010 3:22:44 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: fetching database metadata
Dec 28, 2010 3:22:44 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: updating schema
Dec 28, 2010 3:22:44 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: schema update complete
```

So I can assume some updation went on.  Unable to identify why I am keep getting the old value

**UPDATE**
The complete applicationCOntext.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" scope="prototype">

    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:/bundle/database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>


<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory Definition -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">


    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">
                true
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
                org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Spring Data Access Exception Translator Definition -->
<bean id="jdbcExceptionTranslator"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Template Definition -->
<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcExceptionTranslator">
        <ref bean="jdbcExceptionTranslator" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!--
    ========================= Start of SERVICE DEFINITIONS
    =========================
-->

<!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager Definition -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- AddressBook Service Definition -->
<bean id="loginServiceTarget" class="com.smartcall.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl">
    <property name="loginDAO">
        <ref local="loginDAO" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Login DAO Definition: Hibernate implementation -->
<bean id="loginDAO"
    class="com.smartcall.dao.hibernate.HibernateLoginDAO">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate">
        <ref bean="hibernateTemplate" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transactional proxy for the AddressBook Service -->
<bean id="loginService"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref local="transactionManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="target">
        <ref local="loginServiceTarget" />
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="get*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
            <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

context.refresh() refreshes the whole applicationContext beans I thought.  Ok now I removed those delgate and service in between and the application now calls straight

I am not using DBSettingsDelegate now

**UPDATE**

update properties file code

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
    String a = Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource("/com/smartcall/bundle/database.properties").getFile();

    a = a.replaceAll("%20", " ");
    String url = "";

        url = "jdbc:mysql://"+theServerName+":3306/"+theDatabaseName+"?characterEncoding=UTF-8";
        File file = new File(a);
        //file.setWritable(true);

        System.out.println(url);
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        properties.load(stream);

        properties.put("jdbc.username", theUserName);
        properties.put("jdbc.password", thePassword);
        properties.put("jdbc.url", url);            

        properties.store(new FileOutputStream(file),null);
```

Comment: ??? I don't understand the question. What do you want?

Comment: @Sean Sorry for not making my question clear. I created a dbsettings page where user can enter which database they want to connect to.  To achieve this I need to update database settings programmatically. So I tried the steps above

Comment: @Sean Is my comment clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [refresh](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#refresh%28%29) your Application context and get the bean `DriverManagerDataSource` again in order to reflect the changes written to propertie files.

```
context.refresh();
DriverManagerDataSource databaseSource = (DriverManagerDataSource)context.getBean("dataSource");
databaseSource.getUsername();
```

**Tip for getting File object of your resource:**

```
    URI a = getClass().getResource("/com/smartcall/bundle/database.properties").toURI();
    File file = new File(a);
```

You will not need to decode the path, i.e. replacing %20 with " ". [Referrence](http://gigadot-blogger.blogspot.com/2010/10/loading-classpath-resources.html)

Comment: Is the error being thrown at the line context.refresh()? It does not seem like it is being thorwn at that line. Can you check what is your line 41, 49 in DbSettingsBean.java and line 38 in DbSettingsDelegate.java? those are where the error is thrown. Did you get some other bean from the context too? if so, you will need to get it again. If you need more help, please show me your DbSettingsBean.java and DbSettingsBean.java.

Comment: @gigadot Thanks for the comment.  I will check it and get back to you

Comment: Your applicationContext.xml does not contain only those two beans, right? It also have the the definition of dbSettingsService? If you get any bean from the context somewhere else, when you call the refresh method the referrences to the beans elsewhere will not be updated.

Comment: If dbSettingsService depends on your context, make sure it is also updated. Otherwise will point to the old beans before refreshing. As you can see, it is the design problem. There is no easy way to this problem except reloading your webapp. Many webapps uses this approach but I don't like it either.

Comment: BTW, is it neccesary to have DbSettingsDelegate class? Are you making extra work to keep track of the changes? Another thing, from you stack trace, I cannot tell if the error is being thrown from the section of servlet code you pasted above. None of the code lines involve DBSettingBean and DbSettingsDelegate classes. Maybe it is thrown somewhere else later on? Try debugging or print longer stack trace.

Comment: @gigadot Thanks for your detailed reply.  I thought of using Business delegate pattern which is similar to the one I found in JContact in Sourceforge.  Ok I will rework with things and get back to you.

Comment: @gigadot I have reworked the code and cut down DBSettingsDelegate and DbSettingsService.  No error comes now, but the new value is not updated.  Also check my update

Comment: Sorry for troubling you. Nothing sucked more than this

Comment: @mvg Did the exception is thrown when context.refresh() is called?

Comment: Please update your question with full sources of DbSettingsDelegate.java including import section.

Comment: Also, I have asked a number of questions about you context settings, it will be very helpful if you can answer them. I have very limited information here.

Comment: @gigadot Thanks for your patience. I will update all your questions

Comment: Please try to debug while keeping the following tips in mind: 1. Normally, you should ask yourself which null object causes the NullPointException. But in your case, the null object is hidden behind the Spring framework which is extremely difficult to find. 2. The cloest invocations in your stack trace to the exception are in DBSettingsDelegate and DbSettingsService, so there may be bugs in there. 3. Is dbSettingsService dependent on context (even if implicitly)? if so, when you refresh context, will this pointer get updated. I believe it is not.

Comment: Actually as I said above no error comes now and the old values remains.  I have removed DBsettingsDelegate and service.  I will debug more and get back to you.  Thanks again for your patience

Comment: Are you sure reloading the Spring application context in a web app is thread safe?! Unless you can guarantee there are no other concurrent requests to the app server, I think you will continue to see random errors / exceptions because there could be database transactions in progress.

Comment: @AngerClown This is thread safe, since only one user uses at the time.  As per @gigadot suggestion I changed the code and now no error comes.  But the old value remains still and this puzzles me.  Any clarification?!

Comment: The question is getting too long. If this is an open-source application, it will be easier to point me to your repository. Finding out about why getting NullPointExcept under frameworks requires knowing many parts of the codes.

Comment: @gigadot As per your suggestion I removed delegate and service class.  No exception comes now. That may be due to the design.  My question is why the old value remains even though I use context.refresh()?

Comment: What objects have the old values? All object from your beans after refreshing? have you tried printing the values out right after context.refresh()?

Comment: DriverManagerDataSource has the old value.  I tested it both by printing as well as debugging in Eclipse

Comment: Another possibility: Are you sure you write the new values to classpath:/bundle/database.properties?

Comment: Yeah I printed the path using `file.getAbsolutePath()` and using the path I opened the file manually and found it to be updated there

Comment: How did you get a file object from PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer? There is no method to get a file from PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Is the `file.getAbsolutePath()` the same as `new File(getClass().getResource("/bundle/database.properties").toURI()).getAbsolutePath();`?

Comment: Note: I'm not worried about the file object you just write but I want to make sure that the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is loaded from that file.

Comment: What will happen if you change your `classpath:/bundle/database.properties` to `classpath:com/smartcall/bundle/database.properties` or `classpath:/com/smartcall/bundle/database.properties`? Is the values still the same?

Comment: @gigadot You made it!!!!!!!!   I changed the code to `classpath:com/smartcall/bundle/database.properties` and the code worked.  Can you tell what is the real problem behind?  It will be useful for me. Since I am a beginner

Comment: You read/write the file from differnt places. The xml bean is config to read from "${classhpath}/bundle/database.properties" but you are writing it to "${classhpath}/com/smartcall/bundle/database.properties".

Comment: @gigadot ok!  Thanks for sparing your time!  Happy new year!

Comment: You should read up a bit more about closing `InputStream` and `OutputStream`. From the section of code you use to update property file, you did not close them. You will have complication later on if you forget to close them.

Comment: Also check the tip i wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

The values are read when the application is started, they are set to the target objects (the data source in your case), and the properties file is no longer being read. So even if you change the values, they are not reflected anywhere.

For the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to reload the values you'd have to extend it and specify a reload period. But that still won't update the data source. You should also extend the data source class and make it re-read properties after a given interval. Or you can declare the `DataSource` to be of scope `prototype`, so that a new instance is obtained.each time, and the properties - reloaded.

This is if you don't want to restart the whole context (which might take a lot of time)

Comment: +1 for the explanation.  I don't want to reload properties file at the specified interval.  I just want to reflect the changes immediateley after the user update database setting.  Regarding the 2nd point do I need to update applicationcontext file with this  <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" scope="prototype"> I did that but no success

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your context? Since your context is small, you may not need to worry about taking a lot of time.

Comment: @mvg I have never used it this way. My suggestion is to check what is the runtime type of your context object using debug tools. If it is an AbstractApplicationContext or any derived class of AbstractApplicationContext, you can change its type.

Comment: According to Spring API, all implemented WebApplicationContext classes should be derived from AbstractApplicationContext. I would say it is safe to change the field type to AbstractApplicationContext.

Comment: NullPointerException could be anything. You'd have to debug that, I can't help more.

Comment: @Bozho As I said in my first comment, I added scope="prototype" in applicationContext.xml file.  But no success.  Am I missing anything?