# Database Connectivity Tomcat Struts2 Application

Tags: maven, tomcat, web-applications, struts2

I have an application that is currently deployed in multiple locations using Maven profiles which select a different property file depending on the profile and then deploys the application using cargo plugin to the relevant tomcat instance.

I'm hearing about JNDI and completely separating the database settings from the webapp itself however I'm not sure where to start looking for the best solution.

Problem:

- Maven Struts2 project deployed to multiple instances of Tomcat with different databases depending on environment.

What is the best way to manage the database connections and any other differences for different environments? (such as Struts2 `devMode`)

Comment: There are a ton of ways to do this, including JNDI, environment variables, custom property file loaders, file string  replacement, etc. It's tough to even know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

The best way IMHO use the data source and apply database settings to it. Then you need to adjust the configuration each time you build for different environment. Other option is to use embedded database, however.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? What datasource/database settings?

Comment: A factory for connections to the physical data source that this DataSource object represents. The Database settings is considered in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530193/update-database-settings-in-properties-file-in-spring)