# Modify property of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring

I have a class that extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer where I´m injecting some properties with values form database. My question is, if once that I have my application spring running, would be possible to update a property value that I have on memory on PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Regards.

Comment: I think this blogpost describes perfectly what you need: [Modification of properties in spring - propertyplaceholderconfigurer](https://web.archive.org/web/20150402034811/http://jeviathon.com/2009/08/25/modification-of-properties-in-spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer/)

Comment: That´s is more or less what I have. I have a class that extends PropertyPlaceHolderConfig, but still dont explain how to get a property value already loaded and modify it:        getConfigurer().getResolvedProps().get(key);

Comment: In my case I load the propertyPlaceHolder during the startup, but I need to update some property values once the application is up and running, and a user interact with the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to refresh your Application Context and get the new bean?

check out the post on [Update database settings in properties file in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530193/update-database-settings-in-properties-file-in-spring)