# Can not update config file using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, configuration

Could it be possible to update property using [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html/)

applicationContext.html

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"></property>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:config.properties" />
</bean>
<bean id="appConfig" class="com.abc.Configuration">
    <property name="myProperty" value="${config.request.myProperty}" />
</bean>
```

Configuration.java

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class ServerConfig {
    private int myProperty;
    public int getMyProperty(){return myProperty;}
    public int setMyProperty(int value){this.myProperty = value }
}
```

config.properties

```
myProperty=123456
```

I can get "myProperty" value using getMyproperty(). But i can not update property using setMyProperty() - The config file was not update, so new value will be lost if application was restart.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: check out the post on[update-database-settings-in-properties-file-in-spring][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530193/update-database-settings-in-properties-file-in-spring
 may this help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating properties like that will not work. You need to access the configuration file directly and write your changes to it. The problem is that PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer may read from different types of sources (in your case classpath resource). Some of them may be read-only.

Also keep in mind that event if you make changes they will not be automatically picked up. You'll have to refresh the spring context. Or you can use some dedicated configuration library (e.g. [cfg4j](http://www.cfg4j.org/))

Comment: New to this! Just think that if I can get, then i can set!!! The only thing i need was write new value for property. Because new value was remain in ServerConfig when app is still running.

Comment: Extended my answer. If you find it helpful can you please up vote it and mark as correct?